# What is the dimension of the kernel of a functional?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over field $\Bbb{K}$ of dimension $n$, and $\phi$ a functional from $V$ to $\Bbb{K}$. Assume $\phi\neq 0$.

The question is: What is the dimension of the kernel of $\phi$?

How can there be one answer to this? Doesn't the dimension of the kernel depend upon the functional under consideration?

This question is from Lang's "Linear Algebra (Second Edition)" (pg. 165).

Motivation:

Let $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ be the basis of $V$. Then a transformation of the form $(0,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n-1})$ has the subspace generated by $v_1$ as the kernel. The functional $(0,0,b_1,b_2,\dots,b_{n-2})$ has the subspace generated by $v_1,v_2$ as its kernel. And so on

Here $a_1,a_2,\dots,b_1,b_2,\dots$ are all scalars belonging to the scalar field $\Bbb{K}$.

Comment: Rank-nullity theorem: the rank of $\phi$ is $1$, so the nullity is $n-1$.

Comment: Do you remember the rank formula?

Comment: If we did not have the condition $\phi \neq 0$, then it would indeed depend upon the functional under consideration.  However, all non-zero functionals will have the same kernel-dimension.

Comment: @DanielFischer- Kindly check the updated description.

Comment: @egreg- Kindly check the updated description.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom- Kindly check the updated description.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan note that a functional refers specifically to a map $\phi:V \to \mathbb{K}$.  The maps you describe a functions from $V$ to $V$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom- How is that? Take any $v\in V$ as $(a,b,c,\dots,n)$. Take a functional as $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$. Here $a_i$ is the scalar in $\Bbb{K}$ that the functional maps the basis vector $v_i$ to. When you multiply the two vectors together, you get a scalar in $\Bbb{K}$. It's a form of dot product.

Comment: I don't understand what you're describing.  Can we make a concrete example?  Take $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$, $V = \mathbb R^3$.  Construct such a functional $\phi$.  What are $\phi(1,0,0), \phi(0,1,0),$ and $\phi(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom- Take $\phi(1,0,0)=1, \phi(0,1,0)=2, \phi(0,0,1)=3$. Then the matrix representation of $\phi$ would be $(1,2,3)$. Now take any vector in $\Bbb{R^3}$, say $(7,8,9)$. Then this vector will be mapped to $(1,2,3)(7,8,9)^T$ by $\phi$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan and the kernel of the functional would be the span of the vectors $(3,0,-1)^T$ and $(0,3,-2)^T$, which is indeed $(3-1)=2$-dimensional

Comment: @Omnomnomnom- Yes but what about the functional $(0,0,1)$? Wouldn't the kernel here be 2-dimensional? The whole vector subspace generated by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$?

Comment: Yes.  Any non-zero functional from an $n$-dimensional vector space has an $(n-1)$-dimensional kernel.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom- I'm so sorry for the extended discussion. I meant what about $(0,1,1)$? Wouldn't the kernel here be one dimensional? Namely the vector subspace generated by $v_1$?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan what about $v_2 - v_3$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** as $\ker\phi\neq V$ you can write $\ker\phi\oplus H = V$ for some $H\neq \{0\}$.
Then you can prove that $f:H\to K$ defined by $f(x) = \phi(x)$ is one to one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments: this question is quickly answered using the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: In the [link given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), I have a doubt regarding the first proof. All it seems to say is that if the dimension of the kernel is $a$, then the dimension of the image is $n-a$. It doesn't say anything about the correlation between the dimension of the kernel and the rank of the transformation matrix. What am I missing?

Comment: "Rank" simply means "the dimension of the image"